# Plotting log likelihood function of Pareto distribution inR

Tags: r, distributions, data-visualization

How can I plot log likelihood function with type "I" Pareto distribution function $f(x|\alpha,k)=\alpha k^\alpha/x^{\alpha+1}$ in R?  The problem for me is there are two parameters, how can I plot the log likelihood with two unknown parameters? Do I need to give a value of $\alpha$ and then plot the log likelihood function with respect to single parameter $k$?

Answer (score 1):

**It is crucial that you get the PDF right.**  It is *not* $\alpha k^{\alpha} / x^{\alpha+1}$; rather, it is equal to that expression *only* when $x \ge k$.  Otherwise it equals zero.  This makes an *enormous* difference: in effect, the log likelihood is defined only for those values of $k$ not exceeding the smallest of all the data values.

At this point there are many standard ways to plot $\log(f)$.  We tend to think in three dimensions and so will favor a pseudo-3D plot of $\log(f)$ against $k$ and $\alpha$:

[image: 3D plot]

It can be difficult to read such plots quantitatively, though; for such purposes, people favor contour plots:

[image: Contour plot]

The lighter shading corresponds to larger values of log likelihood: evidently the maximum is reached near $k=3.03$ and $\alpha \approx 1.35$.  The contour lines are drawn for integral values of $\log(f)$.

Sometimes, for more detailed evaluation it does help to look at "profile" log likelihoods.  Here, we look at different slices of $k$ ranging from the minimum value of $x$ (green curve) and then decreasing by $0.01$ with each slice.  These correspond to some of the mesh lines seen in the first figure:

[image: Slices]

---

The *Mathematica* code which generated these data and drew these plots is:

```Mathematica
x = RandomReal[ParetoDistribution[3, 4/3], 100];
logLikelihood[x_, {k_, a_}] := 
  Sum[If[y >= k, Log[a] + a Log[k] - (1 + a) Log[y], -Infinity], {y, x}];
ContourPlot[logLikelihood[x, {k, a}], {k, Min[x] - 10/Length[x], Min[x]}, {a, 1, 5/3},
  FrameLabel -> {k, a}]
Plot3D[logLikelihood[x, {k, a}], {k, Min[x] - 10/Length[x], Min[x]}, {a, 1, 5/3},
  AxesLabel -> {k, a, Log[f]}, Boxed -> False, PlotRegion -> {{0.05, .95}, {0, 1}}]
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[logLikelihood[x, {k, a}], {k, Min[x] - 12/Length[x], Min[x], 4/Length[x]}], 
  {a, 1, 5/3}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {a, Log[f]}]
```

A histogram of the data is

```
Histogram[x]
```

[image: Histogram]

The methods in `R` are similar but take more effort to make them this nice.  Look at `curve` and `graphics::filled.contour`.  I am not aware of anything really comparable to the first (pseudo 3D) plot; there are some crude 3D utilities.

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually I want to use a graph to show that the log likelihood function cannot be differentiated with respect to k in order to find the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE). How can I express the third graph in terms of parameter k?

Comment: You just slice in the other direction.  But obviously the log likelihood *is* differentiable in $k$: it equals $n\alpha/k$ for $n$ data values.  Thus all the slices will be portions of lines. The issue here is that the log likelihood will be maximized by a value of $k$ *on the boundary of its domain*: this is at the extreme right hand side of the contour plot, for instance.  Thus, at the maximum, the derivative with respect to $k$ *exists* but it is not zero.

Comment: i cannnot run the codes in R. Are these codes in R? there is no "RandomReal" in R.